# Ext.net Numberfield restricted input to only 2 optional decimals with input mask

Tags: c#, regex, input, ext.net

I need a configuration for numberfield in Ext.Net, but I can't find the right input mask that optionally allows until two decimals (third decimal and so on are discarded, if the user press the key is totally ignored). The number of natural numbers could be anything. Negatives numbers are forbidden.

My cases:

- 54 -> accepted
- 155,89 -> accepted
- 10.234,01 -> accepted
- 5,2 -> accepted
- 1,23 -> accepted
- 12,258 -> forbidden
- 1,2,5 -> forbidden
- sdf123 -> forbidden

This is what I've tried so far (C# code):

```
X.NumberFieldFor(m => m.MyPoperty).ID("MyId").HideTrigger(true).MaskRe(@"/[\d,]/")
    .Plugins(X.InputMask().ClearWhenInvalid(false)
    .Mask("9?999,99")
    );

X.NumberFieldFor(m => m.MyPoperty).ID("MyId").HideTrigger(true).MaskRe(@"/[\d,]/")
    .Plugins(X.InputMask().ClearWhenInvalid(false)
    .Mask("x,tt")
    .MaskSymbols(symbols =>
    {
        symbols.Add(new MaskSymbol() { Name = "x", Regex = @"/^[0-9]*$/" });
        symbols.Add(new MaskSymbol() { Name = "t", Regex = "[0-9]" });
    })
    );

X.NumberFieldFor(m => m.SuperficieRealSol).ID("MyId").HideTrigger(true)
    .Plugins(X.InputMask().ClearWhenInvalid(false)
    .Mask("x")
    .MaskSymbols(symbols =>
    {
        symbols.Add(new MaskSymbol() { Name = "x", Regex = @"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$" });
    })
    );

X.NumberFieldFor(m => m.MyPoperty).ID("MyId")
    .AllowExponential(false)
    .DecimalPrecision(2)
    .MinValue(0)
    .HideTrigger(true);
```

I think the problem here is the matching between the regex and the mask symbols. I can't see how to configure mask and masksymbols to match more than one key input.
For instance, if my mask is

> x,t

- x would be any natural number `\d+`, it doesn't matter the number of digits.
- t would be `(?:,\d{1,2})?`

But this approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by `decimals` ? And, why is `12,258`  not allowed ?

Comment: The numbers after the decimal mark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Comment: The user only want to input two numbers, not more.

Answer (score 1):

The regex that describes all of those things is
`@"^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d{1,2})?$"`

If you could describe a single mask, it should work.

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 \d+ 
 (?:
      \. \d+ 

 )?
 (?:
      ,
      \d{1,2} 
 )?
 $
```